# React Array.find() not working while setting input's defaultValue to a string from array of objects

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm trying to populate the values of my questions (`<label>s`) and answers(`<textarea>`)s in a form dynamically. The values of questions is received as an Object from server:

```
questions: {
"q1": "Question 1",
"q2": "Question 2",
"q3": "Question 3",
... up to q11.
}
```

And the values for answers are received as:

```
Answers:
[{"q":"q1","ans":"answer to q1"},{"q":"q4","ans":"answer to q4"}]
```

both the questions and answers are stored in state with the same names and the initial state is:

```
questions: {}
answers: []
```

The questions are rendered properly but for the answers I get `Cannot read property 'ans' of undefined`

The form looks like this:

Why isn't `this.state.answers.find(answer => answer.q === questionNumber).ans` working here? Or am I doing something wrong?

This is how I set the state:

```
componentDidMount() {
fetch(`http://localhost:3002/api/questions`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
        }).then(res => {
            if(!res.ok) {
                throw `Error getting questions\n${res.statusText}`;
            }

            return res.json()
        }).then(data => {
            this.setState({questions: data.questions, answers: data.answers});
        }).catch(err => {
            throw `Error getting questions\n${err}`;
        });
}
```

This is how I try to get data from state and populate the fields

```
 render(){
        return (
            !this.state.questions ? <h2>No Questions Found</h2> :
            <div>
               <form className="questionaire">
                   {Object.keys(this.state.questions).map( (questionNumber, index) => {
                       return (
                       <label className="questions" key={`${questionNumber}`}>
                        <span>{this.state.questions[questionNumber]}:</span>
                        <textarea name={questionNumber} defaultValue="" onChange={this.handleFormChange}></textarea>
                        </label>)
                   })}
                   <button id="info-submit" onClick={this.submit}>Submit Information</button>
               </form>
            </div>

            )
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking to make sure the find function finds any items in the answers array before trying to access the `ans` property.

Note the `answer` variable within the key iteration of the questions:

```
{Object.keys(this.state.questions).map((questionNumber, index) => {
          const answer = this.state.answers.find(
            answer => answer.q === questionNumber
          );
          return (
            <label className="questions" key={`${questionNumber}`}>
              <span>{this.state.questions[questionNumber]}:</span>
              <textarea
                name={questionNumber}
                defaultValue={answer ? answer.ans : ""}
                onChange={this.handleFormChange}
              />
            </label>
          );
        })}
```

Here is a working example (modified version of the other answer's code): 
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-maxwell-v259z

Answer (score 0):

How's you state set up?

When trying to reproduce your problem, I was able to make it work by setting the component up like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    questions: {},
    answers: []
  };


  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        questions: {
          q1: "Question 1",
          q2: "Question 2",
          q3: "Question 3"
        },
        answers: [
          { q: "q1", ans: "Question 1's answer" },
          { q: "q2", ans: "Question 2's answer" },
          { q: "q3", ans: "Question 3's answer" }
        ]
      });
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="questionaire">
        {Object.keys(this.state.questions).map((questionNumber, index) => {
          return (
            <label className="questions" key={`${questionNumber}`}>
              <span>{this.state.questions[questionNumber]}:</span>
              <textarea
                name={questionNumber}
                defaultValue={
                  this.state.answers.find(answer => answer.q === questionNumber)
                    .ans
                }
                onChange={this.handleFormChange}
              />
            </label>
          );
        })}
        <button id="info-submit" onClick={this.submit}>
          Submit Information
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

If your answers need to wait for an async response, maybe your problem could be around that area, but again I need to see how you're setting up your state.

Executable code:

[image: Edit divine-night-sq7qm]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I think you're right. I set the state after I get response from ```fetch()```. I have updated the question and included rest of the code too. Can you please take a look? Thanks!

Comment: @AbbyKhan, can you update your answer with the JSON response that comes back from your API? The reason I ask is that even if I set a timeout in the `componentDidMount` function to fake an async call, the code still works.

Comment: updated the question - I also included my render method. Thanks!

Comment: @AbbyKhan, just noticed you found your answer! Let me know if there's anything I can do to help. Enjoy your day.